# How can I repair this damaged ceiling?

Tags: repair, ceiling, crack

[image]

I've already scored the loose pieces of the crack with a utility knife. Now, it's just as simple (?) as making both sides of the ceiling even so I can repair it.

What could I do to even out both sides? I tried screwing in the side that's leaning down but unfortunately, that accomplished nothing. I was using drywall screws.

I believe this ceiling is drywall.

Comment: unless your drywall screws go into something solid behind the drywall (a ceiling joist for instance), you won't be pulling anything even. The only drywall repairs I know to make are cutting out the damage and inserting a new piece of drywall in it's place - using blocking to drive the screw into. Easy enough to do, but I've never been able to get the texture to match.

Comment: Jim that comment could be an answer.